# Wake on Lan doesn't work on wan

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, kali-linux, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to setup wake on lan. My router doesn't allow port forwarding to broadcast so I've binded the mac address of my system to a static ip in the router's control panel. I've also forwarded port 9 to the ip I've set, so when the router gets a request it should forward it to the mac address of my computer. The only problem is that, for some reason, the computer wakes through lan but not through wan. I'm using android's WolOn app to send the magic packet and I've Kali linux installed on my system. My router is a TP-Link TD-W8961ND ver 3.0. Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: I've run tcpdump, turns out that my machine receives the magic packet both on lan and wan. For some reason, it doesn't wake on wan. Could it be that the system refuses wan magic packets? They seem to be different from the lan ones

Answer (score 0):

From Wiki:

It is possible to launch a Wake-on-LAN through the Internet, to a machine located behind a NAT router, but this under certain conditions: the magic package must be a UDP packet, whose used port is redirected to the IP address of the machine that needs to be awake. The computer is off, so it is necessary to permanently configure the MAC address / IP address association in the ARP table of the router (otherwise, this association expires in the router after about 5 minutes, and the magic package will not be directed to the machine). Some routers can wake a machine from the local network through their web interface or via telnet.

When you say : I've binded the mac address of my system to a static ip in the router's control panel ...

> Have you add an entry into ARP table ?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that my router has the possibility of configuring a static ARP table. I guess that I can't do it that way. Would configuring a virtual lan solve my problem?

Comment: I do not know, sorry but I think first of all that you have to make sure, if the router reboots for example, it MUST have static ARP input from the computer off that it needs to wake up, you can not get around this point without having access to the setting of the ARP table of the system in one way or another. This is the router on fire and it is he who receives the packets, so it is he who needs to be configured. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I've discovered that in Windows there's a command, "arp -s" that binds an ip to a mac. Is this what I am looking for? Or Will this work only when the pc is on?

Comment: Yes but for your TP-LINK router ... because your 'gateway' is the router , not your windows client.

Comment: From internet source: static ARP settings should be in /etc/ethers and whatever handles network ups/downs should execute 'arp -f /etc/ethers'. But probably your TP-Link router, without root access, not allow you to change this.